# No overload for method `HideToast' takes `0' arguments

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, arguments, overloading

My question is what parameter do I put in when using NSTimer? Anything I tried hasn't worked.

```
v.AllTouchEvents += delegate { HideToast();};

NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer (theSettings.DurationSeconds, HideToast);

void HideToast (NSTimer tr)
{
    UIView.BeginAnimations ("");
    view.Alpha = 0;
    UIView.CommitAnimations ();
}
```

The error is: `No overload for method 'HideToast' takes '0' arguments`

Comment: maybe v.AllTouchEvents += delegate {HideToast(NSTimer);}; is your solution.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately that hasn't worked since NSTimer is a type and not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign your event

```
 v.AllTouchEvents += HideToast;
```

I hope I've got your point.

**Edit**

If the HideToast signature is diffrent from what AllTouchEvents need
after typing `v.AllTouchEvents +=` press tab and let it create the proper method (event handler )for you. In your case it probably creates a method like

```
private v_AllTouchEvents(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Inside the generated method you should put your desired code.

Good luck.

Comment: I tried that and got this error. A method or delegate 'app.iOS.ToastView.HideToast(Foundation.NSTimer)' parameters do not match delegate `System.EventHandler(object, System.EventArgs)' parameters